# Keras training with multiple GPU and traceback the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'"

Tags: keras, lstm, tensorflow

I have tried my code on a CPU only computer and it runs correctly. But after I changed into GPU version, an error " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update' " is popped out. Does anyone help me to solve it?

Part of my source code is as following:

```
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import tensorflow as tf`
...
def train_validation_test_model(model, X_tr, Y_tr, X_ts, Y_ts, filepath):
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Training...')
    X_mag_tr = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(X_tr))
    X_mag_ts = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(X_ts))
    EarlyStop = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 10, verbose = 0, mode = 'min')
    CheckPoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor = 'val_loss', save_best_only = True, mode = 'min')
    opti = optimizers.Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opti, metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit(x = X_mag_tr, y = Y_tr, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 500, verbose = 2,
                    callbacks = [EarlyStop, CheckPoint],
                    validation_data = (X_mag_ts, Y_ts),
                    shuffle = True)
    return history

def My_Model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(BatchNormalization(batch_input_shape = (None, time_step, input_size)))
    model.add(LSTM(units = cell_size,
                   batch_input_shape = (None, time_step, input_size),
                   return_sequences = True,
                   stateful = False, kernel_initializer = Init.orthogonal(), name = 'LSTM_1'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization()
    model.add(LSTM(units = cell_size,
                   return_sequences = True,
                   stateful = False, kernel_initializer = Init.orthogonal(), name = 'LSTM_2'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(output_size, kernel_initializer = Init.lecun_uniform(),
                                    activation = 'softmax', name = 'Output_Layer')))
    return model

X, Y = load_dataset()
idx = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0]) # shuffle the dataset
X = X[idx, :, :]
Y = Y[idx, :, :]
...
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model = My_Model()
pmodel = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus = 2)
X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = generate_2sets(X, Y, fold+1, n_fold)
History_ = train_validation_test_model(pmodel, X_train, Y_train, X_test, 
Y_test, model_path)
...
```

And then I got the following Tracback information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/XXX/Python/XXX/Mynet.py", line 226, in <module>
    History_ = train_validation_test_model(pmodel, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, model_path)
  File "C:/XXX/Python/XXX/Mynet.py", line 148, in train_validation_test_model
    shuffle = True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1657, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in _fit_loop
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 73, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 415, in on_epoch_end
    self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2556, in save
    save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 108, in save_model
    'config': model.get_config()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2397, in get_config
    return copy.deepcopy(config)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 218, in _deepcopy_list
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 223, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 223, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 223, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 223, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\copy.py", line 306, in _reconstruct
    y.__dict__.update(state)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

The platform I used is Windows 10. The version of tensorflow is 1.4.0, and the version of keras is 2.1.2 and it's backend is tensorflow.
GPUs are GTX 1080 Ti with driver version 385.28; CUDA 8.0.61win10; cuDNN-8.0-windows10-x64-v6.0; Python 3.5.2.

Comment: I'm having  the same error and looking for solution

Comment: Do you save the model after training? How do you save it?